# How to handle multiple rest API on the same route with Express?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm new to JavaScript programming, I'm trying to build a rest API of soccer game stats with express JavaScript,

I properly built a rest API that handles leagues creation/shows all league/update/delete/ and I made a controller with all that functions and used the specific function on the specific route like [www.test.com/soccer/leagues](http://www.test.com/soccer/leagues), [www.test.com/soccer/league:id](http://www.test.com/soccer/league:id) ecc. And all worked very good.

Now I want to make the rest API that handles the teams, but I want to show all the teams that play in a specific league in that specific league view at the route like [www.test.com/soccer/league:id](http://www.test.com/soccer/league:id).

I made a new controller with all the functions to create team/update team/show all teams/delete a team and linked that controller to the team routes like [www.test.com/soccer/leagues/team:id](http://www.test.com/soccer/leagues/team:id)

My question is how I have to handle it? How can I pass the teams data to the league: id get route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design) on REST API design to get some ideas on how to show relationships between collections.

Generally if you have a "one-to-many" (one league to many teams) relationship between datasets, you have a couple options for querying "child" collections in the API. One option is to add a "nested" route that exposes a child collection:

```
www.test.com/soccer/leagues/:id/teams --> Gets you all teams for provided leagueID
```

This will require a new route where you consume the id from the route parameter and use it to filter the results.

Another option is to use query parameters to filter results on the child collection as a whole:

```
www.test.com/soccer/teams?league_id=123 -> All teams for league_id 123
```

This option could allow you to use your existing "teams" endpoint. You would consume the query parameter, and filter results if the parameter is present.

Also note that we use plural names for our endpoints to represent that we have many items in each collection.